# Rails 5 Action Mailer - Prawn PDF wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have set prawn in my rails app to generate:

```
   format.pdf do
             pdf = SalesByDayPdf.new(@daily_salesnp, @amount_total, @discount_total, @grand_total)
             pdf.render_file "daily_sales.pdf"
             send_data pdf.render, filename: 'daily_sales.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'

        end
```

And this is my SalesByDayPdf

```
def initialize(daily_salesnp, grand_total, discount_total, amount_total)
    super()
    @daily_salesnp = daily_salesnp
    @amount_total = amount_total
    @discount_total = discount_total
    @grand_total = grand_total

    header
    text_content
    table_content
    footer
  end
```

This works fine.

Now I want to send this pdf from action mailer. I have set it in my DailySalesMailer as:

```
def send_daily_sale(daily_salesnp, grand_total, discount_total, amount_total)
    @daily_salesnp = daily_salesnp
    @amount_total = amount_total
    @discount_total = discount_total
    @grand_total = grand_total

   attachments["daily_sales.pdf"] = SalesByDayPdf.new(daily_salesnp, grand_total, discount_total, amount_total)
   mail(:to => "email@gmail.com", :subject => 'Sales by Day Report')

end
```

So basically I copied the pdf generator in mailer and passed same arguments defined in my controller.

But I'm getting:

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 4)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please add more logs?

Comment: i dont see any error related to prawn. Can you please add send_daily_sale method call with arguments?

Comment: sorry what do you mean? how do i do that?

Comment: also note that is this line that raises the error ` def send_daily_sale(daily_salesnp, grand_total, discount_total, amount_total)`

Comment: here you have added method definition but where you invoke the mehtod?

Comment: I have added this to my index controller   DailySalesMailer.send_daily_sale(@daily_salesnp, @amount_total, @discount_total, @grand_total).deliver below format pdf do. So that when I go to the pdf page it should also send an email. But now I get undefined method `length' for #<SalesByDayPdf:0x007f6b6b126280>. The line that raises the error is attachments["daily_sales.pdf"] = SalesByDayPdf.new(daily_salesnp, grand_total, discount_total, amount_total)

Comment: can you please add SalesByDayPdf method definition?

Comment: ok i have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to modify the attachment to:

```
attachments["daily_sales.pdf"] = SalesByDayPdf.new(daily_salesnp, grand_total, discount_total, amount_total).render
```